# Refractive index for gamma rays, is it $1$?

Tags: speed-of-light, gamma-rays

In (1) it says (in the context of PET imaging):

> The speed of gamma-radiation in every material is the same as in the vacuum: $c=3\cdot 10^8 m/s$.

I realize that if this is true then it is only an approximation. Please can someone show me where this approximation comes from and how it is made?

**References**

(1) Biophysics Problems: A Textbook with Answers by P.Maroti, L.Berkes and F.Tolgysi (page 451)

Comment: For the application described the approximation is made because the refractive index is very close to 1 as shown in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3608v2.pdf and this article http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2012/05/gamma-ray-bending-opens-new-door-optics.

Answer (score -1):

If the (effective) speed of photons in a certain medium remains unchanged, that would imply that the photons are not interacting the particles of said medium whatsoever.

I find that hard to believe, since gamma radiations is ionizing radiation, meaning that the photons interact well and good (and violently:) with the electrons of the atoms of the medium.

(I know this doesn't answer your question completely, but what I'm saying here that this approximation seems silly to me, considering my current knowledge of EM radiation)

Comment: Note that scattering off an individual electron is quite a different question than the high energy photon interacting with the (collective) material. It is the latter that leads to the dielectric constant. As the photon energy goes higher and higher, it basically decouples from the material, since there are no material states with a matching energy to interact with anymore. So, yes, for high energy photons (including most gammas), the dielectric constant is really close to 1 (not perfectly, but close enough to just be considered 1.000)